# Tomcat with SSL enabled behind an ELB

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, amazon-elb

My current setup is as follow

```
ELB (80)  ----- > (8080)
ELB (443) ------> (8080) (with a certificate installed in the ACM)
```

So from the client to ELB the connection secure but from the ELB to my app the connection becomes insecure.

I would like to archive this:

```
ELB (80)  ----- > (8080)
ELB (443) ------> (8443) (with a certificate installed in the ACM)
```

I would like to start having my Tomcat running on 8443 with SSL enabled.
Is it correct to say that I will need to install the same certificate that is currently installed on the ELB ?

Or will installing a 'self signed' localhost certificate on the Tomcat be enough ?

I'm asking because I did tried the above but didn't seem to work and I don't know if it is because I wrongly configured tomcat or because I need a proper certificate. I'm not entirely sure how the ELB forwards the SSL requests to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Yes it is possible to use a self signed cert

```
ELB (HTTP 80)  ----- > (HTTP 8080)
ELB (SSL 443) ------> (SSL 8443) (with a certificate installed in the ACM)
```